# Вывод информации из select

Tags: html, php

```
$img_path =normalvar($_POST['gems']);

<form action="index2.php" method="post">
<select name="gems" size="1">
<option value="gem">Камень</option>
<option value="Amethyst">Аметист</option>
<option value="Emerald">Изумруд</option>
<option value="Ruby">Рубин</option>
<option value="Topaz">Топаз</option>
</select>
</form>

for ($j = 0 ; $j <= 5 ; ++$j)
{
echo <<<_END
<div><img width="32" height="32" src="css/img/$img_path/$j.png" alt="" /><p>$profit[$j]</p></div>
_END;
}
```

Хочу сделать вывод картинок из разных каталогов, но почему-то не работает. Вместо $img_path пустое место. Подскажите, в чем же ошибка?

Comment: echo $img_path; что выведет?

Comment: ничего, только пустоту

Comment: Попробуйте написать кнопку отправки. Это должно помочь решить проблему

Comment: node_pro можете привести пример кода? я не совсем понял вас

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно я ошибаюсь, но всеже попробуйте мой код.

```
 <form action="index2.php" method="post">
    <select name="gems" size="1">
    <option value="gem">Камень</option>
    <option value="Amethyst">Аметист</option>
    <option value="Emerald">Изумруд</option>
    <option value="Ruby">Рубин</option>
    <option value="Topaz">Топаз</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="ok" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Идеально, спасибо. Отправка была в соседней форме, видемо надо добавлять кнопки во все формы.

Comment: Обращайтесь =)

Comment: Столкнулся с проблемой, если отослать результат через эту кнопку, то результат следующей формы не считается. Можно ли как то совместить?

Comment: т.е у вас еще одна форма есть? А объединить под одну форму не выйдет?

Comment: тогда попробуй сделать чекбоксами . . .  http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml5/formy/flazhki